# Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on 5 node cluster with 7core each and 25GB per node. My current execution uses 1-2GB input data, Can i know why am i getting below error?
I use pyspark dataframe (spark 1.6.2)

```
[Stage 9487:===================================================>(198 + 2) / 200]16/08/13 16:43:18 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 3 on server05: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
[Stage 9487:=================================================>(198 + -49) / 200]16/08/13 16:43:19 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 1 on server04: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
[Stage 9487:=========>                                          (24 + 15) / 125]16/08/13 16:46:38 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 2 on server01: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
[Stage 9487:==========================================>        (148 + 30) / 178]16/08/13 16:51:36 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 0 on server03: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
[Stage 9487:=============================>                       (50 + 12) / 91]16/08/13 16:55:32 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 4 on server02: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
[Stage 9487:============================>                       (50 + -39) / 91]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/example.py", line 397, in <module>

  File "/home/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 269, in count
  File "/home/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/home/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
  File "/home/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o9162.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ShuffleMapStage 9487 (count at null:-1) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 577
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutpu
```

How can i change the below groupBYKey to ReduceByKey. Python 3.4+, spark 1.6.2

```
def testFunction (key, values)
    << Some statistical process for each group>>
    << each group will have n (300K to 1M) rows>>
    << i am applying statistical function to each group>>


resRDD = df.select(["key1", "key2", "key3", "val1",  "val2"])\
           .map(lambda r: (Row(key1 = r.key1, key2 = r.key2, key3 = r.key3), r))\
           .groupByKey()\
           .flatMap(lambda KeyValue: testFunction(KeyValue[0], list(KeyValue[1])))
```

Comment: Most likely you ran into OOM. Pasting your code could be helpful.

Comment: Its huge code.It uses statsmodels.formula.api for some statistical calculation. Which will be pure python code called from lambda and groupby key

Comment: `groupByKey` is quite prone to OOM. You may want to consider `combineByKey` instead. However it may not be possible since many stats cannot deal with incremental computation.

Comment: Thanks ShuaiYuan,  I have updated the snippet of lambda code, can you tell me how can i rewrite the same using reduceByKey?. Thanks in advace

Comment: If your `testFunction` requires the full dataset to compute, you cannot use `reduceByKey`.

Comment: Why do you use a `Row` object as the key? That is quite unusual.

Comment: Yes. My test function need entire data of that group (1-1M)  with key and few columns (10-15 columns), But my return from testFunction  will be 1 row per group( 3 keys and result filed). I will be returning ROW.. i can convert to any format if it boost the performance.   If not reduce by key then can i go with df.groupBy(keys).map(lambda x:testfunction(x))

Comment: What's the best way to determine if Spark has run out of memory, or to monitor its memory usage? I often see people blaming OOM but have yet to come across a best practice for tracking memory usage.

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this problem by decreasing `spark.executor.memory`. Perhaps there are other applications other than spark running on my cluster. Eating up all those memories slows down my workers and hence causing communication loss.

Comment: Why decreasing the memory will help? I thought that you need to add memory. Have something you base on?

Comment: @SantiagoP No rigorous base but experiment. My cluster is in stand-alone mode without any resource manager. An application will eat up all that is configured as it can once it has been submitted, plus some extra memory of python since I used  `pandas_udf`. As a result, all memory and a portion of swap are used of my cluster which makes it very hard to communicate with it that I can't even open spark web UI. So I guess the RPC failure due to the same reason and I decreased the memory, try to make space for inter-cluster communication and it just worked!

Comment: I very much appreciate you posting a non-intuitive answer after figuring it out.  I wonder, Large allocations of memory require large pauses to clean.  I wonder if changing the garbage collection might have also 'fixed it'.