# dataframe.rdd.isEmpty() is throwing error while df.head(1) works

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Getting the below error while checking if dataframe is empty using `dataframe.rdd.isEmpty()` in spark 2.4. Sometimes it is working but some times throwing the below error for same data frame.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 32.0 
failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 32.0 (TID 28) (10.139.64.4 
executor 9): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 9 exited caused by one of the running tasks) 
Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated
```

Is there any way to make this work consistently ?

I have used df.head(1), which is working, but I want to know the root cause this failure with df.rdd.isEmpty(), as we are using this in all over the code.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38935358/8279585). it is likely running out of memory.